# new created zen subtheme - content offpositioned

Tags: 7, theming

I just created a new zen subtheme using drush. Everything went smooth but I think there is some kind of problem with css - #content container is completely off positioned from page. I did not make any changes to files. Is it some kind of bug or this needs some tweaking? 
I have sass and compass installed. I use zen 7.x-5.5 version.
Please see screenshot.[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh.  I had this same problem yesterday and it turned out that I was using the wrong version of compass.  I installed version 0.12.6 and the content returned to where it was supposed to be.
You can either unistall compass and then reinstall 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088454/how-do-i-downgrade-to-an-old-version-of-compass-using-gem-instal

or just add the old version and explicitly invoke the older version like so:
compass *0.12.6* watch